Vertex AI for text generation in ASP.NET
Is there a way to use Vertex AI API for text generation using Google cloud service account?
I used only an API key later (.NET System.Net.Http.HttpClient). But now, I need to use Google cloud service account because of easier billing things.
I've tried to use nuget package Mscc.GenerativeAI and Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 + System.Net.Http.HttpClient, but it returns a error "403 forbidden" without any additional info in both ways.
I granted Google cloud service account what it is required.
gcloud cli is installed and authorized with the same project as an application default.
